# JDO and inheritance in Google App Engine: how to query entities with "complete-table" strategy?

Tags: google-app-engine, inheritance, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

I'm developing an application using Java Runtime and JDO/Datastore for persistence on Google App Engine. I've created a hierarchy of model classes using the "complete-table" strategy, like this:

```
@PersistenceCapable
@Inheritance(customStrategy = "complete-table")
@Discriminator(strategy=DiscriminatorStrategy.CLASS_NAME)
public abstract class A {
    ...
}

@PersistenceCapable
public class B extends A {
    ...
}

@PersistenceCapable
public class C extends A {
    ...
}
```

JDO correctly persists entities of class B and C in a single table using a discriminator value. However, if I try to do this:

```
PersistenceManager pm = PMF.getPersistenceManager();
B result = pm.getObjectById(B.class, aKeyOfAnObjectOfClassC);
```

where `aKeyOfAnObjectOfClassC` is a Key that refers to an object of type C (who'd have thought it), JDO returns an object of class B without batting an eyelash (i.e. nothing strange appears on logs). Members that come from A are different from null, while others are null.
I'm quite puzzled by this behaviour. Isn't the discriminator value meant to be used for **discriminating** instances when performing queries like this?

Thank you all :)

Comment: Define what you mean by "google-app-engine" here ... "google-cloud-sql" persisting to MySQL ? or using GAE/Datastore ? obviously the log tells you what is happening, so i'd expect you to refer to it

Comment: Thank you for your comment, sorry If I missed a crucial information like that :) I'm using GAE Datastore, I edited the post to make it more clear. Regarding logs, GAE logs do not show anything strange

Comment: If you're trying to DEBUG the problem you aren't necessarily looking for "something strange" ... set it to DEBUG level and see what the log says when you do the getObjectById ... if it fires a query for example, and what query

Comment: It's just that, prior of going through my code searching for some bugs, I wanted to be sure that it is NOT the intended behavior :)